# Add outargument from activity to a Dictionary via Expression Editor

Tags: workflow

I want to add the outcome of my activity (using the expression editor) to an existing dictionary which is a workflow variable so something like..

```
dictionary.Add("key", this)
```

Or am I missing something here? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly I think I can help you.

Add it like that:

```
New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"MyParam", "ItsValue"}}
```

I've found it here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/02eb6512-e6db-44ec-a8ca-8126dea3a8a4